# Java Compare Two List's object values and store uncommon objects in 3rd list?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, equals

ListA and ListB both contains TrackingBean objects ,now I have to compare both the list's object values here name as well age variable

```
ListA = ["Raj",20],["Narayan",25],["Sree",32];

ListB = ["Raj",20],["Narayan",25],["Sree",32];
```

In the above scenario ListC size will be zero because both list are same.

```
ListA = ["Raj",20],["Narayan",25],["Sree",32];

ListB = ["Sree",32],["Raj",20],["Narayan",25];
```

Now also I should get ListC size as zero. **Above scenario is irrespective of order of objects.**

```
ListA = ["Raj",20],["Narayan",25],["Sree",32];

ListB = ["Sree",32],["Raj",20],["Narayan",25],["Srinivas",18];
```

In the above scenario ListC Should store new object:

```
ListC=["Srinivas",18];`enter code here`
```

Could you suggest me a java code for implementing the above one??
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to create two sets from lists A and B.  Then you can use `Set.removeAll()` to find those elements in sets A and B which are unique to each set.  Your original question omitted information in this regard, but each set could have an element which does not appear in the other set.  My answer takes the union of all elements which do not intersect.  If you want the difference from only one set against another, you can modify accordingly.

```
Set<TrackingBean> sA = new HashSet<TrackingBean>(listA);
Set<TrackingBean> sB = new HashSet<TrackingBean>(listB);

Set<TrackingBean> diffA = sA.removeAll(sB);
Set<TrackingBean> diffB = sB.removeAll(sA);

Set<TrackingBean> diffTotal = new HashSet<TrackingBean>();
diffTotal.addAll(diffA);
diffTotal.addAll(diffB);
```

Comment: what about `list.retainAll()` method?

Comment: @AsteriskNinja Unless I read wrongly, the OP does not want to _retain_ elements in common, it wants to _remove_ them.  Hence, `removeAll` makes sense here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `listA.retainAll(listB)` and use `ArrayList`

Answer (score 0):

I know correct answer has been given although i want to add something to existing answer

you can use @ Tim Biegeleisen

But Make sure you have overriden *`equals()`* method and *`hashCode()`* methods
without overriding these two methods in your bean class both methods won't work